# Generalization of computability to continuous for loops?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, physics, church-turing-thesis, mu-calculus

A computable function, formulated in the sense of mu recursion, can compute a for or do loop over some (possibly infinite) integer range.

I was wondering if a suitable generalization exists that allows the computation of a real-domain function $f$ where $f(x)$ can be calculated given the values of $f(y)$ for all real $y<x$. This seems natural to ask, given that it is relevant if you want to describe e.g. a real-world physical system as an algorithm.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51682/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152915/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).